# mutate on condition

Tags: r

I have a data set like this:

```
dt <- tibble(
TRIAL = c("M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1"),
  PLOT= c(1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 2, 3, 1,67,34),
  trait = c("ASI", "ASI", "ASI", "ASI", "ASI", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR"),
  trialValue = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, , , , , ,)
)

# # A tibble: 11 x 4
 #      TRIAL     PLOT  trait           trialValue
        <chr>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl 
  #1   M20-01RND1   1    ASI                2
  #2   M20-01RND1   2    ASI                2
  #3   M20-01RND1   3    ASI                2
  #4   M20-01RND1   1    ASI                2
  #5   M20-01RND1   6    ASI
  #6   M20-01RND1   3    CUR
  #7   M20-01RND1   2    CUR
  #8   M20-01RND1   3    CUR
  #9   M20-01RND1   1    CUR
  #10 M20-01RND1    67   CUR
  #11 M20-01RND1    34   CUR
```

This is what I want to achieve:I want a new column data_qc_code to be mutated if the required conditions are met. i.e trait = "ASI" & traitValue = 2  give "A", and when traitValue is empty then give "M"

```
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
 #     TRIAL      PLOT  trait    trialValue  data_qc_code
       <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl         <chr>
 #1   M20-01RND1    1    ASI          2            Q
 #2   M20-01RND1    2    ASI          2            Q
 #3   M20-01RND1    3    ASI          2            Q
 #4   M20-01RND1    1    ASI          2            Q
 #5   M20-01RND1    6    ASI                       M
 #6   M20-01RND1    3    CUR                       M
 #7   M20-01RND1    2    CUR                       M
 #8   M20-01RND1    3    CUR                       M
 #9   M20-01RND1    1    CUR                       M
 #10 M20-01RND1 67   CUR                           M
 #11 M20-01RND1 34   CUR                           M
```

When I run this code I get not the expected output

```
df %>%
  mutate(data_qc_code = case_when(
           trait == "ASI" & traitValue == 2 ~ "A",
              traitValue == ""  ~ "M"))->df1
```

This was my output

```
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
#     TRIAL       PLOT   trait    trialValue    data_qc_code
     <chr>        <dbl>  <chr>      <dbl             <chr>
  #1   M20-01RND1   1    ASI         2                 Q
  #2   M20-01RND1   2    ASI         2                 Q
  #3   M20-01RND1   3    ASI         2                 Q
  #4   M20-01RND1   1    ASI         2                 Q
  #5   M20-01RND1   6    ASI                                                    
  #6   M20-01RND1   3    CUR                                                  
  #7   M20-01RND1   2    CUR                                                  
  #8   M20-01RND1   3    CUR                                                  
  #9   M20-01RND1   1    CUR                                                  
  #10 M20-01RND1    67   CUR                                                  
  #11 M20-01RND1    34   CUR
```

Kindly help out please.
Thank you.

Comment: How are you able to create the tibble? R throws an error for me as it does not allow empty arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in `R`, missing value is represented by `NA`. Therefore I changed your input a little bit to avoid errors and to include `NA`.

Note that in your question, you said you want to fill the first criteria with "A", but in your codes, it's "Q". Therefore I also used "Q" in my code.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt <- tibble(
  TRIAL = c("M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1", "M20-01RND1"),
  PLOT= c(1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 2, 3, 1,67,34),
  trait = c("ASI", "ASI", "ASI", "ASI", "ASI", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR"),
  trialValue = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

dt %>% mutate(data_qc_code = ifelse(trait == "ASI" & trialValue == 2, "Q", "M"))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 5
   TRIAL       PLOT trait trialValue data_qc_code
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       
 1 M20-01RND1     1 ASI            2 Q           
 2 M20-01RND1     2 ASI            2 Q           
 3 M20-01RND1     3 ASI            2 Q           
 4 M20-01RND1     1 ASI            2 Q           
 5 M20-01RND1     6 ASI            2 Q           
 6 M20-01RND1     3 CUR           NA M           
 7 M20-01RND1     2 CUR           NA M           
 8 M20-01RND1     3 CUR           NA M           
 9 M20-01RND1     1 CUR           NA M           
10 M20-01RND1    67 CUR           NA M           
11 M20-01RND1    34 CUR           NA M
```